# Subspace as system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a subspace we can write the subspace as a condition on the $b$ vector ($ax=b$) so in our case the column space

$\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & -3 &3 &2 &x \\
-2 &3 &-1 &-1 &y\\
0 & 3 &1 &2 & z\\
2 & 3 &3 &5 &w
\end{pmatrix}$

row reducing the systems give use conditions on the vector that in the span, namelly

$\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & -3 &3 &2 &x \\
0 &0 &2 &1 &x+y\\
0 & 6 &2 &4 & w+y\\
0 & 0 &0 &0 &w+y-2z
\end{pmatrix}$

So for a vector to be in the span of the columns or in this case after the row reduced form the  column space its need to satisfy $w+y-2z=0$ so the $x$ coordinate get any value at it is  $0x+w+y-2z=0?$

Solving for $0x+w+y-2z=0?$ we will get the column space?

Comment: $x$ can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The column space of the given matrix is the set of vectors $(x,y,z,w)$ that satisfy the constraint $w + y - 2z = 0$. So, not only can $x$ be arbitrary, you can also take $y$ and $z$ to be arbitrary, and then describe $w$ in terms of $y$ and $z$. Hence, the column space is the set
$$
\{ (x,y,z,2z - y) \in \mathbb{R}^4 : x,y,z \in \mathbb{R} \}.
$$